# Solace multiple consumers for a queue not working

Tags: solace, solace-mq

We have a java spring-dsl intergration program and running with 10 consumers configuration but out of 10 only 3 are working fine. For other I'm getting below errors:

```
 DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Q-TEST-POC' - trying to recover. Cause: Error creating session - max transacted sessions exceeded (503: Max Transacted Sessions Exceeded)
```

Any setting need to done on SolAdmin so that multi consumer can able to get access or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your "Max Transacted Sessions" setting in your client-profile is too low for your application.

To modify this in SolAdmin:

1. Go to the "Clients" tab.
2. Select the "Client Profiles" View.
3. Edit the client profile used by your application.
4. Select the "Advanced Properties" tab.
5. Adjust the "Max Transacted Sessions" limit.